# MATLAB stoped working after I installed Maple

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu-18.04, maple

I installed Maple and give it the path to MATLAB and now MATLAB can't start. It looks like MATLAB is trying to find something but can't.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.

Here is the output when I run the MATLAB command in the terminal:

```
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/libmwi18n.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/libmwi18n.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/libmwmvm.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/libmwservices.so)
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/MATLAB: /home/lucasrj/maple2020/bin.X86_64_LINUX/system/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/local/MATLAB/R2020a/bin/glnxa64/libmwcpp11compat.so)
```

Many more similar lines are produced, I've put the full output in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/2qDE42Qm).

Comment: It looks like your directory links got broken when you installed Maple in the MATLAB directory. You can either rebind all the links by hand, or simply reinstall MATLAB and Maple, and give them different paths that time.

Comment: How did you install Maple? Did you change your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable? Your error message indicates that Maple’s older `libstdc++.so.6` is shadowing your system’s version. This should never happen in an official installation of professional software.

Comment: i install maple with maples own installer, then i ran the installer i found matlab on my system and asked for the location of matlab